# I get this error from lftp mirror: Fatal error: 500 Data has changed elsewhere, cannot resume

Tags: mirroring

And I don't know how to make it recover. Not even sure what it means.
I don't want it to resume, I want it to overwrite the file from scratch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I had --continue set on, and it couldn't continue. Removed it and voila.